# Summing Fields in a mongo document

Tags: mongodb, sum, mongodb-query

Seems like every question I find that is similar always answer the wrong "thing".  I have a data set, simple documents (not sub-docs).  Each document has six fields that are basically bit fields.  Every document should have at least one of these fields true (1) but all the others must be false (0).  I figured the easiest way to tell which documents are out of compliance with this rule is to sum the six fields for each document and if it is greater than 1, it's a fail and I want to pull the document out into a collection of those document so I can find/query it for more information or just display it.

So,

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("598d5fbd8b157042cc12e5bf"), 
    "FirstName" : "fred", 
    "Hispanic" : NumberInt(1), 
    "Indian" : NumberInt(0), 
    "Asian" : NumberInt(0), 
    "Black" : NumberInt(0), 
    "Pacific" : NumberInt(0), 
    "White" : NumberInt(0), 
    "Unknown" : NumberInt(0) 
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("598d5fbd8b157042cc12e5c0"), 
    "FirstName" : "joe", 
    "Hispanic" : NumberInt(0), 
    "Indian" : NumberInt(0), 
    "Asian" : NumberInt(0), 
    "Black" : NumberInt(0), 
    "Pacific" : NumberInt(0), 
    "White" : NumberInt(1), 
    "Unknown" : NumberInt(0)
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("598d5fbd8b157042cc12e5c1"), 
    "FirstName" : "margie", 
    "Hispanic" : NumberInt(1), 
    "Indian" : NumberInt(0), 
    "Asian" : NumberInt(0), 
    "Black" : NumberInt(0), 
    "Pacific" : NumberInt(0), 
    "White" : NumberInt(1), 
    "Unknown" : NumberInt(0)
}
```

the solution would return back one of these fields because if you add up all the race identifiers I'm supplied with, it will be "2" while the others will be 1.

Still pretty new to Mongo and the samples have been helpful but so far all I've find seem to revolve around summing sub-document data to determine the selection of a document and everything I try is just returning nothing.  Like is this a group (don't think so) or a project; do I sum and add [fields] or just sum...I get a little confused.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it well, you need something like this:

```
db.yourCollection.aggregate(
    [
        {
            $project: {
                total: { $add: [ "$Hispanic", "$Indian", "$Asian", "$Black", "$Pacific", "$White", "$Unknown" ]}
            }
        },
        {
            $match: {
                "total": {"$gt": 1}
            }
        },
    ]
);
```